# How to customize LinearProgressIndicator

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have a LinearProgressIndicator implemented like the following:

```
LinearProgressIndicator(
       backgroundColor: Colors.red,
       valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.white),
)
```

Now I want to make the animation slower than the default speed.
And I want the white area to have a gradient from white to red.
I can't find any examples for that. Hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 0):

We can't get the gradient in LinearProgressIndicator. But you can use this package to achive something similar to that.

https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator

Also if you are good with canvas, you can create your own LinearProgressIndicator with your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, do you have an idea how to make the animation slower without a package?

Comment: Sorry mate, I don't know that.

Answer (score 0):

For make animation slower than the default speed, you can copypast code of standart *LinearProgressIndicator* and change *Duration*.

[image]

If you want to customize colors you can use *ShaderMask*

[image]